# Navigating from one table view to another table view on selecting a particular cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a view based application which consists the following files

1. The main view controller which has a button
2. The display view controller which will display a set of countries in the form of a table
3. The states view controller which will display a set of states for the countries selected in the 2nd step in the form of tables again

It's *button --> countries(tableview)* and after selecting a cell *--> states(tableview)*.

Well, everything works fine, except I can't navigate to the states of the countries when I click on a particular country. Eg. if I select AUS then I don't get states of AUS.

The code is as follows.

#### The main view controller which has a button:

.h file

```
    { 
     IBOutlet UIButton *btn;
    }
    -(IBAction)click;
```

.m file

```
    -(IBAction)click
        {

            display *dis=[[display alloc]initWithNibName:@"display"bundle:nil];
            [self presentModalViewController:dis animated:YES];

        }
```

#### The display view controller

.h file

```
                    @interface display : UITableViewController
        {
            NSArray *countries;
        }
        @property(nonatomic,retain)NSArray *countries;

        @end
```

the display.m file

```
                - (void)viewDidLoad {
                   NSArray *count=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"India",@"USA",@"UK",@"AUS",@"SA",@"PAK",@"BANGLADESH",nil];
                    self.countries=count;
                [count release];
                self.countries=count;
                    self.title=@"Select a Country";
                    [super viewDidLoad];

                }

                - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
                    // Return the number of sections.
                    return 1;
                }


                - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
                    // Return the number of rows in the section.
                    return [countries count];
                }


                // Customize the appearance of table view cells.
                - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

                    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";



                    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
                    if (cell == nil) {
                        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
                    }

                    // Configure the cell...
                    //countries=
                    cell.textLabel.text=[countries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                    return cell;
                }

                - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
                    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
                    //UITableViewCell *thiscell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                    if(indexPath.row==0)
                    {   
                     states *detailViewController = [[states alloc] initWithNibName:@"states" bundle:nil];
                     // ...
                     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
                        //detailViewController.indexPath=self.indexPath;
                        //self.dis.indexValue=indexPath;
                     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController  animated:YES];
                        //detailViewController.indexPath=self.indexPath;
                        [self presentModalViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

                     [detailViewController release];
                    }
                    if(indexPath.row==1)
                    {
                        states *detailViewController = [[states alloc] initWithNibName:@"states" bundle:nil];
                        // ...
                        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
                        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
                        [self presentModalViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

                        UITableViewCell *cell=[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                        [detailViewController release]; 

                    }

                    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
                }
```

#### the statesenter code here controller

states.h file

```
            @interface states : UITableViewController {
                NSArray *state;
                NSArray *state1;
                NSArray *state2;
                //NSIndexPath *indexPath;
            }
            @property(nonatomic,retain) NSArray *state;
            @property(nonatomic,retain) NSArray *state1;
            @property(nonatomic,retain) NSArray *state2;
            //@property(nonatomic,retain)display *dis;
            //@property(nonatomic,retain)NSIndexPath *indexPath;
            @end
```

the states.m file

```
                     - (void)viewDidLoad {


                        NSArray *sta=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"goa",@"ap",@"karnataka",nil];
                        self.state=sta;
                        [sta release];
                        self.state=sta;
                        [super viewDidLoad];

                            NSArray *sta1=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Los Angeles",@"California",@"Las Vegas",nil];
                            self.state1=sta1;
                            [sta release];
                            self.state1=sta1;
                            [super viewDidLoad];

                            NSArray *sta2=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Southhampton",@"Nottingham",@"London",nil];
                            self.state2=sta2;
                            [sta release];
                            self.state2=sta2;
                            [super viewDidLoad];



                        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
                        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
                    }


                    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
                        // Return the number of rows in the section.
                        return [self.state count];
                    }



                    // Customize the appearance of table view cells.
                    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

                        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

                        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
                        if (cell == nil) {
                            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
                        }

                        // Configure the cell...
                        if(indexPath.row==0)
                        {
                        cell.textLabel.text=[state objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                        }
                        else if(indexPath.row==1)
                        {
                            cell.textLabel.text=[state1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

                        }
                        return cell;
                    }
```

So when I run this code it runs fine, but I get southhampton and california whenever I select any country.

I don't want to create multiple view controllers for all states, it would be foolish to do so. So I created an array and use the states view controller to display different states arrays for the selected country.

How am I supposed to pass the `indexpath` value of countries to the states view controller so that I can access all the respective states of the respective countries? (Note: I haven't created all the arrays for states, just created two to just check.)

Answer (score 0):

hey just use setTableArray of stateView in didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method of countriesView...

setTableArray method like Bellow:

```
-(void)setTableArray:(NSMutableArray *)arr
{
    arrData = arr;
    [arrData retain];
    //[tblView reloadData];
}
```

here arrData is MutableArray....

when you push the stateView fromdidSelectRowAtIndexPath at that time just set aaray like bellow...

```
[detailViewController setTableArray:yourArray];
```

here you just get data with selected country index and pass that array insted of yourArray...
hope, this help you...
:)

Answer (score 0):

First thing why you are comparing indexPath in  didSelectRowAtIndexPath of display view controller?You can put code like this also. if you only want to pass indexPath:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //UITableViewCell *thiscell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    states *detailViewController = [[states alloc] initWithNibName:@"states" bundle:nil];
    //Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    detailViewController.m_SelectedIndexPath=indexPath;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController  animated:YES];        [self presentModalViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
 }
```

and In states.m, cellForRowAtIndexPath you can check m_SelectedIndexPath like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];}

 // Configure the cell...
 if(m_SelectedIndexPath == 0)
 {
     cell.textLabel.text=[state objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 }
  else if(m_SelectedIndexPath==1)
 {
     cell.textLabel.text=[state1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 }
  return cell;
 }
```

Second thing you are pushing as well as presenting tableview.You should push or present.

Comment: hey thanks for the help..one last favour,i had tried this before too..but i didnt know where to declare the m_SelectedIndexPath,coz it keeps asking me request for member 'm_SelectedIndexPath' is not a structure or union,where should i declare that? and is it NSUInteger type?

Comment: Declare that as member variable in states.h and do not forget to synthesize in states.m.You can declare it as follows:int m_SelectedIndexPath; and @property(nonatomic, assign)int m_SelectedIndexPath;

Comment: hey i tried your code..but i cant see the names of the states,it gives a warning abt passing argument1 of 'setm_SelectedIndexpath' makes integer frm pointer without a cast...

Comment: Sorry instead of indexPath you should assign indexPath.row in didSelectRowAtIndexPath like this:detailViewController.m_SelectedIndexPath=indexPath.row;

Comment: i still cant see my states...:-(